# View not dividing numbers

Tags: sql, join, view

I am trying to create a view that will show the percentage of female users.  I have tried everything I could think of, and haven't been able to find anything that is helpful.  The problem is that the query doesn't divide the numbers, it creates the view, just doesn't do anything with it.

```
select (`TotalFemale`.`Total` / `TotalUsers`.`Total`) AS `PercentFemale` from   (`registerdb`.`TotalUsers` join `registerdb`.`TotalFemale` on((`TotalUsers`.`Total` = `TotalFemale`.`Total`)))
```

Comment: Why do you use so many wrapping brackets?

Comment: I didn't, it was added by phpMyAdmin

Comment: David what is the type of `TotalFemale`.`Total`and  `TotalUsers`.`Total` ?

Comment: Edit your question and include sample data and desired results.  Your query doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe that you really have a table called `TotalFemale`, containing a field called `Total`.

So I would say that you want something like:

```
SELECT (COUNT(*) FROM TotalUsers WHERE gender=`female`)/(COUNT(*) FROM TotalUsers)
```

This is probably not 100% correct syntax but it should give you the idea...

Comment: @ Thomas, I'm not concerned about names because I'm just practicing.  I understand what you mean and will try it.                                               The types are bigint.                                                                        @Gordon,The result I want is .5, what I get is an empty row.

Comment: Anyway, I'm 99% sure that your JOIN clause is wrong, since you don't have a *table* called `TotalUsers` and a *table* called `TotalFemale` with both having a column named `Total`. What you have is just one table, right?

Comment: I agree, it's definitely in the join.  I took it out and tried to divide other things and it is fine, it's when I try to join it.  Let me be more clear about what I have:  View 1 = TotalUsers and it calculates the number of users in at table called Users, View 2 = Total female that calculates the number of users in the table Users, that are female.  What I need is a view that divides View 2 into View 1.

Answer (score 0):

David,
At least two things: 
First, you are joining on TotalUsers.Total = TotalFemales.Total so, assuming there is at least one Non-Female in your database, this will never return a result set.
Once you fix that, you may want to cast as decimal e.g

`CAST(`TotalFemale`.`Total`as DECIMAL(8,4))`

if you are using MySQL; otherwise you are dividing an int by an int which will return an int.

Comment: Thanks Jim, still gave me 0... something's wrong with the join statement.

Comment: David,try `SELECT CAST(TotalFemale.Total as DECIMAL(8,4))/CAST(TotalUsers.Total as DECIMAL(8,4)) FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) as Total FROM your_femal_tables) as TotalFemale CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) as Total FROM your_total_tables) as TotalUsers`